# Anomalous behavior in SQL Server Temp tables

Tags: sql-server-2012, temp-tables

I don't understand why the below code returns the error

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>   There is already an object named '#temptable' in the database.

If lines 1-5 are executed separately followed by lines 6-8, it works fine. I think I am missing something fundamental about how SQL Server processes the queries. Request one of the gurus to shed some light on this issue.

```
select top 10 col1, col2
into #temptable
from tbl

if object_id('tempdb..#temptable') is not null
   drop table #temptable

select top 10 col1, col2
into #temptable
from tbl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code fails when the batch is compiled not when it is executed.

The behavior is documented in [CREATE TABLE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)

> If more than one temporary table is created inside a single stored
>   procedure or batch, they must have different names.